# Benford’s Law by group in R

Tags: r, benfords-law, benford.analysis

I am attempting to implement Benford’s Law using  the benford.analysis package in R across all vendors’ invoices.  Over the entire dataset the data confirms.  I’m trying to find a way to group by vendor to determine if any individual vendor is displaying fraud indicators by not conforming.  Is there a way to break out non-conforming by group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to use `group_by` and `group_map` to create `benford.analysis` plots for each group. In this example, grouping Iris data by Species and performing analysis on Sepal Length variable.

In `group_map()`, `.x` means the grouped subset data, and `.y` means the name of the group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(benford.analysis)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_map(.f = ~ plot(benford(.x$Sepal.Length)))
```

Comment: That worked great! The only thing I’m trying to work out now is how to label the plots by vendor.  We have a lot of vendors and the blank plots on their own are impossible to sort out

Comment: Check out the modified version in this Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/q/56936984/10276092 . (ps. The latest "GitHub" version doesn't make a legend for me)